# Django model choice field Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

I have a model choice field(Many to many relation), When I try to submit the form it throws an error `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

I have also added in `forms __init__` but still facing same error. I think the error is due to string, integer in checkbox value. Can anyone help me to fix this one. Posting my code here

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    telephone = forms.CharField(label=_('Telephone'), required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(status=True), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
        for name, field in self.fields.iteritems():
            attr = {'class': 'custom-class'}
            if field.label:
                attr['placeholder'] = field.label
            field.widget.attrs.update(attr)
```

Categories is the field with many to many selection, which is not allowing me to submit the form.

**Model**

```
class Category(DateUpdate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        {{ form.categories.label }}
    </label>
    {% for check_choice in form.categories %}
            {{ check_choice.tag }}
            {{check_choice.choice_label}}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if form.categories.errors %}
        <span class="error">
            {{ form.categories.errors.as_text }}
        </span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have  `__unicode__`  or   ` __str__`  defined in your model?

Comment: @alix Yes I have `__unicode__` in Category model

Comment: Nothing looks wrong. But, what if you define `categories` under `telephone` not in `__init__`, Like:


`categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(status=True), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)`

Comment: @alix it was like that before and now changed based on some answers in SO. My doubt is data type. In database it is int field and I think while submitting it is trying to save a string. What do you say?

Comment: Normally we shouldn't worry about data types. That's why `ModelChoiceField` exists. Can you post the code `Categories` model and related html code where you render `form`. I want to check on my machine.

Comment: I did not see your `class Meta` in your modelform. I believe you already have it. I added myself. And your `Category` model inherited from a model named `DateUpdate`  which i don't see also :)) Anyway, I tested your code and submitted the form. It worked :/ . no error.

Comment: I solved it by changing `ModelChoiceField` to `ModelMultipleChoiceField`